# Paypal Sandbox test payment

Tags: php

I have a Buy Now button on my site. When I logged in to the PayPal sandbox and clicked on the Buy Now button through my site, it was redirecting to the desired page from where I could log in with the buyer's email id and password.

But when I was *not* logged in to the PayPal sandbox first, after clicking on the Buy Now button the page was redirecting to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

When clicking on the PayPal sandbox link, the page was redirecting to the site https://developer.paypal.com/ where I was trying to log in as a buyer, but it showed this error:

***The email address or password you have entered does not match our records. Please try again.***

However, I am confident that I am giving the right information to log in as a buyer.

Can someone explain how to make a test payment?

Comment: Are you trying to make a test payment? Or an actual payment?

Comment: I am trying to make a test payment

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a 'normal' email address/password for this.

Login to your developer account and click "Create a preconfigured account" and add the details in - take note of the email address and the password you enter (the email address will look a little funky)

When prompted to login within the sandbox, use the email address and password you created inside your developer account to login.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The reason why it happens is because, for some reason you need to go to https://developer.paypal.com and login, create the test business account and personal account, and stay logged in during transactions.

This means every pc you run a test transaction through paypal sandbox, you should be logged into your account on https://developer.paypal.com.

This may just be a bug in and walk around solution for this but it worked for me.